# Montserrat font/package, "invalidfont" error when printing

Tags: fonts, pdftex, pdf, postscript

I'm using the `montserrat` package to use the Montserrat font and I'm having troubles printing the resulting PDF.

This is a trivial minimal example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[defaultfam]{montserrat}

\begin{document}

HELLO WORLD

\end{document}
```

Trying to print the resulting PDF (compiled with `pdflatex`) on the department's Xerox Phaser 7500 results into an error page being printed instead, with the following error printed on it:

```
ERROR:
invalidfont
OFFENDING COMMAND:
define font
STACK:
/Font
--nostringval--
/Montserrat-Regular
-mark-
-mark-
-mark-
-mark-
```

The problem does not reproduce on any other printer I have available (also tried on other types of Xerox printers).

The problem might not be specific to that printer, however, since there is also another easier way to reproduce the problem, as follows:

1. Compile the MWE with `latex`+`dvips`
2. Open the resulting PS file with macOS Preview app
3. Preview fails to show the PS file with a rather generic error ("Unable to convert the 'mwe.ps' file into a PDF file")

[image: error]

However, converting the PS file to PDF using the `ps2pdf` command works, and the resulting PDF file is printed properly. However, I'd avoid passing through `ps2pdf` because of the disadvantages we all know (and the failing printer is the only color printer we have at the department, so I need to use that one).

Any idea on what is happening? is it a bug in the `montserrat` package and/or in the font?

**EDIT**: This is the log when compiling the file: https://pastebin.com/H6L8KC6F

Comment: Opens fine in Okular. Errors/messages from `dvips`? Log?

Comment: Now I've attached the log. I don't see anything strange, unfortunately.

Comment: Curiously enough, after doing `latex gigabytes && dvips gigabytes`, running `gs-X11 gigabytes.ps` shows the page, but `pstopdf` fails with `Error: invalidfont`.

Comment: That’s a good news because it means we have something open source to debug to understand what’s happening!

Comment: @egreg I don't have `pstopdf`, but `ps2pdf` works fine. (As I guess you'd expect, since `gs` worked.)

Comment: `tllint` reports problems with e.g. `Montserrat-Regular.pfb`. However, it reports some issues with `lmr10.pfb`, too (although not the same ones). I don't know enough to know whether the problems are likely to be problematic in practice or not.

Comment: @cfr Indeed, `t1lint` reports problems with `StemSnapH` and the error with `pstopdf` has `ErrorInfo: StemSnapH --nostringval-- ]`.